# logo hyperlink doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to have a logo inside of my website with a hyperlink linked to youtube inside of it I did this for more website's I build earlier but somehow this doesn't work in this website maybe it has something to do with layers?

Note: I'll just send my whole website, it isn't too big and I don't mind copying because I'm a student and do this to educate :)

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<title>Test Website</title>
<meta name="" content="">

<script type="text/javascript">

        function Slider(){
            $(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
            $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction: 'left'},500);

            var sc=$(".slider img").size();
            var count=2;

        setInterval(function(){
            $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction: 'right'},1000);
            $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'},500);

            if(count == sc){
                count = 1;
            }else{
                count=count + 1;
            }       
        },7000);
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#menubar, #leftmenu, #rightmenu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default scrolling
    var y = $(this.hash).offset().top; // grabs the #id element offset location
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: y-150},750); // animate the scroll
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body onload="Slider();">

<header>

    <div id="title">
    <h1 class="headertext">Test Website</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="menubar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#content">slideshow</a></li>
          <li><a href="#naturepictures">naturepictures</a></li>
          <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#hello">contact</a></li>         
      </ul>
     </div>

</header>
    <div class="hide"></div>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="rightmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#content">slideshow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#naturepictures">naturepictures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello">contact</a></li> 

                <div id="youtubelogo">
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/youtubelogo.gif" alt="" width="90" height="50" align="middle">
                </a>
                </div>

            </ul>
        <div id="righttriangle1"></div>
        <div id="righttriangle2"></div>
        <div id="righttriangle3"></div>
        <div id="righttriangle4"></div>
        <div id="righttriangle5"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#content">slideshow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#naturepictures">naturepictures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="lefttriangle"></div>
        </div>      

        <div id="content">

            <h1>Contentpage</h1><br>

            Picture slideshow
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="slider">
                <img id="1" src="images/car1.jpg" border="0" alt="car1"/>
                <img id="2" src="images/car2.jpg" border="0" alt="car2"/>
                <img id="3" src="images/car3.jpg" border="0" alt="car3"/>
                <img id="4" src="images/car4.jpg" border="0" alt="car4"/>
                <img id="5" src="images/car5.jpg" border="0" alt="car5"/>
            </div><!--slider end-->

            <div class="shadow"></div>  

            <div id="naturepictures">

            <h1>Pictures</h1>
            <br>
            <img style="width: 800px; height: 600px; margin-left: -310px;" src="images/nature1.gif"/>

            </div><!--hello end-->

    </div><!--content div-->

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
*{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sens-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 1200px;
    height: auto;
    background: #fdf7e3;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 10;
}

h1{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.hide
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    z-index:5;  
    height: 123px;
}
.headertext{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#title{     
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: -10px 0 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

#menubar{
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #010000;
}

#menubar ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menubar ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 80px;
}

#menubar ul li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menubar ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#container{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1400px;
}

#rightmenu{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 1280px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 530px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#rightmenu ul li{
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#rightmenu ul li a{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

#rightmenu ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}

#righttriangle1 {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-right: 25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   border-top: 34px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
   margin-top: -410px;
   margin-right: 160px;
}

#righttriangle2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-top: 34px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
    margin-right: 160px;
}

#righttriangle3 {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-right: 25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   border-top: 34px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
   margin-right: 160px;
}

#righttriangle4 {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-right: 25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   border-top: 34px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
   margin-right: 160px;
}

#righttriangle5 {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-right: 25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   border-top: 34px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
   margin-right: 160px;
}

#youtubelogo{

}

#leftmenu{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 450px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #010000;
    border-right: 2px solid #010000;
}

#leftmenu ul li{
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#leftmenu ul li a{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

#leftmenu ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}

#lefttriangle{
    margin-top: 112px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-left: 82px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 82px solid transparent; 
}

#content{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 160px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#naturepictures{
    color: black;
    top: 1200px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 440px;
}

.naturepicture{
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
}

.slider{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.shadow{
    background-image:url(../images/shadow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    width: 850px;
    height: 144px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.slider img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance and I hope you can get a solution fast! (It will probably be something stupidly easy :p)

Comment: don't just post code for code sake, point us at the issue, you mention a logo, why isn't a link working? You mentioned layers, have you removed layers over the link maybe (a guess here)

Comment: I made a youtube logo inside #rightmenu with an image, and in that image I made a hyperlink but somehow the link doesn't show me the youtube page I don't really know what the issue is I tried many things already..

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a `<div>` element the direct child of a `<ul>` element. You'll need to wrap the `<div>` inside of a `<li>` element first.

Try this instead

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#content">slideshow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#naturepictures">naturepictures</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hello">homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hello">contact</a></li> 
    <li>
        <div id="youtubelogo">
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/youtubelogo.gif" alt="" width="90" height="50" align="middle" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your href is working good just try it in another page it works good. problem is somewhere else. may be it's in your js

Comment: What is your problem?picture logo is not coming?

Comment: Tell me as soon as possiable

Answer (score 0):

Can you uopload a screenshot?

Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE approves your code.

[image]

Here's a Screenshot.

Comment: you can Edit your post and click on the picture icon (indicated here http://oi43.tinypic.com/swe5hw.jpg) or you can upload the image to tinypic.com or another image service.  @abdul-jabbar-webbestow may have the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine after updating.If you logo related problem then copy and paste the below code instead the previous code!

```
            <div id="youtubelogo">

            <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/youtubelogo.gif" alt="" width="90" height="50" align="middle">
            </a>
            </div>
```

check your image format from the images folder like .gif,.png etc
[image]